# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "tirarse el rollo"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, coloquialismos, españa

¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "*tirarse el rollo*"?

Esta expresión viene a significar "hacerle un favor a alguien".

> El profe de matemáticas se *tiró el rollo* y me ha aprobado con un 4.9
>
> Alberto se *tiró el rollo* y nos invitó a todos a unas cañas
>
> Anda, *tírate el rollo* y hazme este favorcito, que no te cuesta nada.

Nada en la [etimología de rollo](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?rollo) o en los usos de algunas palabras derivadas de esta, como *arrollar* o *desenrollar* sugieren la idea de "hacer un favor". Sin embargo, estoy seguro de que relacionada con esta expresión está el coloquialismo *enrollarse*.

> [enrollar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FaO1IdN)
>
> 3. tr. coloq. Convencer a alguien para que haga algo, liar. *Enrolló a su padre para que le comprara la moto.*

¿Por qué decimos que alguien *se tira el rollo* (o es un *enrollado*) cuando nos hace un favor?

Comment: Seguramente parecido a _enrollarse_, muy usada también en España.

Comment: "Tirarse el rollo" también se puede usar en el sentido de "rollo" como "mentira, historia inventada": _...como encarnan la muy sexy, natural y reconvertida señora de derechas que se tira el rollo de liberada morbosa y que encarnaba Carmen Maura en Tigres de papel..._

Comment: Quizás   "tirar el rollo"  era simplemente una forma menos elegante de decir  "tender  la alfombra roja" que se usa en el sentido de facilitar el camino o dar una buena acogida a alguien, lo que podría entenderse como hacer un favor.

Comment: Me pregunto si tendrá que ver con "echar un cable/una mano".

Comment: En Chile, "tirarse el rollo" significa en lenguaje coloquial "explicar tu argumento/tesis".

Comment: "Tirarse el rollo" podría venir de terminar con las formalidades, al terminar de leer el papelón formal

Answer (score 4):

Es complicado seguir la pista de estos giros lingüísticos si se dan en tiempos recientes, pero podemos intentarlo.

Comencemos por la palabra *[rollo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=WdApXKx)*. El origen de las acepciones coloquiales de *rollo* se basa en su significado como "pieza de autos", al parecer antiguamente las resoluciones de los autos se escribían en tiras de pergamino que se arrollaban. Imagínate los textos largos que podían salir de ahí, y por eso que en 1970 aparece en el DLE la primera acepción coloquial de la palabra:

> 10. fig. Discurso, exposición o lectura larga y fastidiosa.

En todo caso, antes de 1970 esa acepción ya había dado paso al siguiente coloquialismo, derivado lógico que este significado, que es el de "cosa o persona aburrida":

> *El padre, que visto fuera del coche era aún más feo, comentaba con el tío Emilio que no habían venido antes porque la noche anterior a "la parienta" y a él se les había ocurrido ir a ver una película que les recomendó la tía Rosalía...
>
>   —¡Bueno..., vaya un rollo! —decía, mirando rencorosamente a mi madrina, que intentaba convencerle de que no, de que la tal película era una delicada producción para minorías de René Clair...*
>
> Borita Casas, "Antoñita la fantástica y Titerris", 1953 (España).

A partir de los 80 y 90 el uso de *rollo* sufre una explosión de significados. En el DLE de 2001 ya se admitían las acepciones de "relación amorosa" (elucubración: igual porque para ligarse a alguien tenías que soltarle un rollo), de "impresión" (dar buen o mal rollo), de "modo de ser" (tal vez porque descubres cómo es alguien cuando te suelta su rollo), etc. En 2014 se añadió el significado de "mentira, historia inventada", ya que a fin de cuentas tienes que soltar un rollo (discurso) que alguien se crea.

Por otro lado tenemos la palabra *[enrollarse](https://dle.rae.es/?id=FaO1IdN)*. En 1989 aparece en el *Academia manual* con un significado derivado de la primera acepción coloquial de *rollo*:

> fig. y fam. Liarse a hablar, extenderse en una conversación.

Esta definición se afianzó en 1992. Al igual que antes, para 2001 se había producido una explosión de significados: "convencer a alguien, liar" (porque para convencerlo tienes que soltarle un rollo), "encandilar, sugestionar", "ser sociable" (será que suelta buenos rollos), "tener relaciones amorosas normalmente pasajeras", etc.

Nótese que de estas nuevas acepciones surge además un nuevo uso del participio: una persona *enrollada* es alguien sociable y que te encandila.

Una vez llegados a este punto podemos entender el origen de la expresión con el significado que comentas. El verbo *[tirar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Zr3ZJPx)* tiene suficientes significados como para ser un verbo especialmente maleable. En este caso se usó con la siguiente acepción:

> 35. prnl. Abalanzarse, precipitarse a decir o ejecutar algo. *Se tiró A insultar a todos.*

Luego *tirarse un rollo* podría ser "lanzarse precipitadamente a dar un discurso largo y aburrido", aunque con las nuevas acepciones de rollo la cosa cambia, y de hecho *tirarse un rollo* (o *el rollo* para más énfasis: no ha sido "un" rollo, sino "el" rollo) se empezó a usar con la última acepción comentada de *rollo*: como sinónimo de "mentira".

> *Dios mío, la casa de Rodríguez es la casa del perfecto casado, hay huellas de su familia por todas partes. ¿Por qué te has tirado el rollo de que eres soltero, Rodri?*
>
> ORAL. "Mójate", 09/10/1995, TVE 1 (España).

Sin embargo, esta expresión debió verse influenciada por la otra palabra comentada, *enrollarse*, que al contrario que *rollo* con un acepción negativa de "mentira" llegó a tener un significado positivo con *enrollado*. Esto debió hacer que *tirarse el rollo* pudiera verse como "soltar una mentira audaz y atrevida", que incluso pudiera verse como algo digno de elogio, y de ahí pasaría a tener un significado positivo que acabaría desembocando en *tirarse el rollo* como sinónimo de "ser enrollado", como se ve un multitud de ejemplos coloquiales a poco que busques la expresión en Google:

> *Tírate el rollo e invítame a una copa.*

---

Al final yo sí que he largado un buen *rollo*...