# Raiders of the lost roll // En busca del rollo perdido

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones, significado, españa, dle

La palabra "[rollo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WdApXKx)" se está convirtiendo en una de las más complejas de definir para la RAE, dadas las últimas expresiones que se están generando usando esta palabra. Por ejemplo, Diego ha preguntado por la expresión "[tirarse el rollo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21019/12637)", pero a mí me gustaría ir un poco más allá: ¿qué es exactamente un "rollo"?

Me refiero, por supuesto, a expresiones como las siguientes, popularizadas a partir de la segunda mitad de los años 80 según el CREA:

> Juan vino de buen rollo a la reunión.
>   María y yo tenemos buen rollo.
>   Había un mal rollo increíble aquel día en la playa.

Rebuscando por ahí, encontré [un tuit](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/610787141321408512) en el que la RAE afirmaba que, en esos contextos, la palabra "rollo" significa:

> Ambiente, relación o estado de ánimo.

Les pregunté si tenían planeada la inclusión de dicha acepción en la próxima versión del DLE para la palabra "rollo", y [me dijeron que no](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/867369005748768768), pero que podía solicitarlo a través de su formulario.

Así pues, y antes de plantear una posible propuesta, vamos a ello: ¿cuál creéis que podría ser la definición de "rollo" en los casos propuestos? ¿Veis bien la propuesta de la RAE o añadiríais o quitaríais algo? Entiendo que la propuesta de la RAE encaja con las frases: en la primera significaría "estado de ánimo", en la segunda significaría "relación", y en la tercera significaría "ambiente". ¿Se os ocurren más ejemplos de este uso de la palabra "rollo" pero que atiendan a un significado diferente a los planteados por la RAE?

He aqui las definiciones de la RAE:

> 1. m. Cilindro de madera, metal u otra materia, generalmente dura.
> 2. m. Objeto cuya materia toma forma cilíndrica. Un rollo de carne para guisar. *Hacer un rollo con la masa.*
> 3. m. manga (‖ utensilio para añadir nata a algunos pasteles).
> 4. m. Madero redondo descortezado, pero sin labrar.
> 5. m. Porción de tejido, papel, etc., que se tiene enrollada en forma cilíndrica. *Rollo de estera, de papel.*
> 6. m. Película enrollada en forma de bobina, usada en fotografía y cinematografía.
> 7. m. Canto rodado de forma casi cilíndrica.
> 8. m. Trenza de anea, forrada de pellejo, que se pone entre el yugo y las colleras de las caballerías.
> 9. m. Papiro u otro material laminado que, enrollado, constituía el libro en la Antigüedad.
> 10. m. Columna de piedra, ordinariamente rematada por una cruz, que antiguamente era insignia de jurisdicción y que en muchos casos servía
>       de picota.
> 11. m. Pieza de autos presentada ante los tribunales superiores.
> 12. m. Bollo o pan en forma de rosca.
> 13. m. coloq. Discurso largo, pesado y aburrido.
> 14. m. coloq. Cosa y, por ext., persona, que resulta aburrida, pesada o fastidiosa.
> 15. m. coloq. Mentira, historia inventada o falsa. *Llegué tarde a casa y tuve que contarles un rollo a mis padres.*
> 16. m. coloq. Relación amorosa, generalmente pasajera.
> 17. m. coloq. lorza (‖ pliegue de gordura).
> 18. m. jerg. C. Rica. En lenguaje juvenil, incidente irrisorio.
> 19. m. coloq. Cuba. Discusión acalorada.
> 20. adj. coloq. Aburrido, pesado. *¡Qué novela tan rollo!*

Comment: En Chile no se usa la palabra con el significado de tus ejemplos. Significa "complicación innecesaria", "fantaseo largo y complejo", "dificultad" y también el "neumático" que se forma en el abdomen.

Comment: @Rodrigo en ese caso añado la etiqueta "España" para no llevar a equívocos, gracias por la aclaración.

Answer (score 1):

No me vienen a la mente muchas más acepciones que las que ya te comentaron.

Se me ocurre otro ejemplo, pero creo que se podría traducir como "relación". Es cuando se dice, por ejemplo:

> Juan y María se traen un rollo muy raro entre ellos.

Igual en este caso podría traducirse como "asunto", pero me suena más a "relación".

También está la expresión "Me da mal rollo", cuando te refieres a algo o alguien que te da una mala sensación, algo como "Me da mala espina", pero en este caso creo que también se podría considerar un estado de ánimo.

En cuanto a las que ya te comentaron, se me ocurren (aunque hay infinitos) estos ejemplos:

- Ambiente: "Hay muy buen rollo en mi nuevo trabajo"
- Relación: "Tengo muy buen rollo con mi nuevo compañero de estudios"
- Estado de ánimo: "Siempre procuro estar de buen rollo, ya habrá tiempo para las preocupaciones".

Pero, como digo, las posibilidades son muchas.

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu respuesta! Me vas a tener que disculpar, pero veo que mi última pregunta (la de poner más ejemplos) no estaba bien redactada, y eso te puede haber llevado a confusión. Me refería a ejemplos que usaran la palabra "rollo" de forma similar, pero que impliquen un significado diferente al planteado por la RAE. El caso que propones de "se traen un rollo muy raro" podría valer, ya que (como dices) se podría entender más como "asunto" que como "relación", y por tanto no estaría recogido por la propuesta de la RAE.

Answer (score 1):

*Rollo* es una palabra cuasicomodín, vale para un montón de cosas, es un poco como *movida*, de hecho son intercambiables en algunos contextos. Algunos ejemplos que se me ocurren:

> 1. ¿Te gusta el rap o cuál es tu rollo?
> 2. En esa esquina se ve gente rara que se trae un rollo muy chungo
> 3. ¿Me miras que le pasa al móvil? Yo no entiendo de estos rollos
> 4. ¿Ya has cogido todos tus rollos, nos podemos ir ya?

1. Aquí *rollo* sería "tipo de música" pero en diferentes contextos puede ser distintas cosas, aficiones generalmente.
2. Ya ha salido una frase similar en otra respuesta, aquí podría ser *asunto*.
3. Se podría decir: *Yo no entiendo de estos temas*, también podría ser *asunto* como en la anterior pero tienen un matiz diferente.
4. Aquí *rollos* serían *cosas*, *trastos*, *chismes* o como queramos llamarlos, objetos varios así en general.

Answer (score 0):

No solo podemos ver estas acepciones, por ejemplo, a mi se me ocurre algo así como `envoltura` o `envuelto`, no sé si estaría bien estas palabras pero me explico mejor con un ejemplo.

- **Están los rollos de primavera**. Refiriéndose a comida, algo así como enrollado o envuelto en su propio cuerpo, a su alrededor.
- **Tengo un la cabeza hecha un rollo**. Refiriéndose a que tiene los pensamientos indefinidos, confusos.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que el significado de "rollo" en "rollo de primavera" sí está recogido en el diccionario, y en el segundo ejemplo "rollo" sería sinónimo de "lío". Se aleja bastante de la acepción comentada.

Comment: Yo la verdad es nunca he oído a nadie decir que tiene la cabeza hecha un rollo. Un lío sí, pero un rollo no recuerdo

Comment: No se ustedes donde vivan, yo soy cubana y es bastante frecuente escucharlo, como mismo lo demás aquí expuesto. Un lío, relación con alguien. Disculpen si a lo mejor no entendí bien la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

También se puede decir "Tuvimos un rollo anoche" refieriéndose a un encuentro, no necesariamente sexual, entre dos personas.

EDIT:

En este artículo se ve que, al menos en el título emplean el término "rollo" para referirse a un encuentro casual y sexual. No implica romanticismo de ningún tipo.

https://www.elconfidencial.com/alma-corazon-vida/2016-01-27/por-que-las-mujeres-tienen-rollos-de-una-noche-y-en-que-casos_1142363/