# ¿Cómo se llamaba a los michelines antes de que se creara Michelín como marca?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, coloquialismos, historia, españa

En España (¿y en Hispanoamérica?) es común decir que alguien tiene *michelines* cuando está un poco fofo de la tripa. Más o menos así:

[image]

Esto lo recoge el DLE

> [**michelín**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PAyCXtO)
>   *De Michelin®, marca reg.*
>   1. m. coloq. **lorza** (‖ pliegue de gordura).
>
> > [**lorza**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NcmlNWc)
> >     De *alforza*.
> >     1. f. Pliegue que se hace en una prenda para acortarla o como adorno.
> >     2. f. coloq. Esp. Pliegue de gordura que se forma en alguna parte del cuerpo, especialmente en la cintura.

Nótese que solamente menciona su uso, coloquial, en España.

Y mirando en el mapa de diccionarios veo que la 2.ª acepción de *lorza* no estaba ni siquiera en 2001.

<sub>Curiosamente, el mapa de diccionarios también nos muestra que *alforza* y *alhorza* se utilizaban con mucha más frecuencia que *lorza* en los siglos XVIII y XIX, pero que han acabado desbancados por la palabra más corta.</sub>

*Michelín*, por su parte, no entró en el diccionario hasta 1992.

Todo ello me hace surgir la duda: ¿qué palabras se empleaban anteriormente para denominar la gordura que se acumula en la cintura? ¿cuáles se usan actualmente en Hispanoamérica?

Answer (score 9):

Me cuesta trabajo creer que no esté en el DLE, pero en gran parte de México se les denomina "***lonjas***".

En algunos otros diccionarios he encontrado la definición.

Google Translate recoge :

> Pliegue de gordura que se forma en ciertas partes del cuerpo.
>
> *“aunque adelgacé 5 kg todavía tengo lonjas .”*

Comment: Aquí si aparece: http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=lonja

Comment: Uno que acabo de escuchar hace unos meses en México es que ahora también le dicen *orilla de queso*, supongo que refiriéndose a la orilla de queso rellena de las pizzas. Por ejemplo: "*ponte a dieta que ya se te asoma la orilla de queso.*"

Answer (score 9):

Al menos en Colombia he escuchado la palabra "llanta":

> [**llanta**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NU2U8ku%7CNU2xWhe)
>
> 5. f. coloq. Am. lorza (‖ pliegue de gordura).

Ejemplos:

- Se me sale una llanta.
- Se me ve una llanta.

También se usa la palabra "gordo":

- Se me sale un gordo / gordito.

En este [post](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/lonja-llanta-gordo.1680517/) se menciona *lonja* y *llanta* como usados también en México.

Comment: y para complementar, a la acumulación de grasa a los lados de los muslos les decimos [cartucheras](https://www.elcuerpo.es/las-cartucheras-simbolo-de-salud/) y algunas veces _policias_

Comment: No me sería nada extraño que la palabra *llanta* sea un derivado de Michelín pero haciendo un juego de palabras ya que inicialmente la marca se basó justo en la palabra original *michelín* o *gordos*. Qué se yo jaja, me suena lógico lo que acabo de decir.

Answer (score 9):

En Argentina se les dice comúnmente ***rollos***, que se suaviza a veces como ***rollitos*** (es prácticamente siempre en plural). Menos diplomáticamente también se los llama ***flotadores***.

Comment: ¡Qué bueno! En España la palabra _rollo_ tiene una connotación negativa y se usa para definir algo tedioso: _vaya rollo os he metido en la reunión sobre el nuevo software_, _esta película es un rollo_.

Comment: En España, al menos en mi zona, también se usa lo de los _flotadores_.

Comment: @fedorqui *rollo* vale para muchas cosas, no siempre es negativo: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21037/raiders-of-the-lost-roll-en-busca-del-rollo-perdido

Comment: Se puede agregar que este significado figura en el diccionario de la RAE, como coloquial pero sin indicador regional (acepción 17 de rollo)

Answer (score 6):

En el CORDE se recoge un caso de **lorza** de 1961:

> Vestir a los demás para que luzcan, aguantando mil impertinencias: que si me estira por aquí; que si encoge por allá; que me cae mal; que no me sienta; que me engorda. ¡No le va a engordar, señora, si está usted como una vaca suiza! Que si esta sisa, que esta **lorza**, que este relleno...

Y en el NTLLE aparece desde 1855, como derivado de *alforza* o de *alhorza* como pliegue que se hace en una prenda para acortarla o como adorno. Es posible que se utilizara por similitud con los pliegues abdominales.

Answer (score 5):

Para este tipo de cosas siempre existen los localismos, y siendo América Latina tan extensa seguro que se les dice de diferentes maneras en cada país... En Chile se suele decir ***rollo***: una persona que tiene muchos *rollos* es muy fofa. También ***neumáticos***. A un gordo se le llama *guatón* ya que la ***guata*** es la barriga, según la RAE:

> **guata** 2
>
> Del mapuche *huata*.
>
> **1**. f. coloq. Arg., Bol., Chile, Ec. y Perú. Barriga, vientre, panza.

Pero este vocablo no está presente en ninguno de los diccionarios de los principales misioneros que documentaron palabras del mapudungun.

Comment: Agrego a esta lista de chilenismos la palabra **[charcha](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8cEePLu)**, que si bien significa _"acumulación de grasa, especialmente en el vientre"_, en la actualidad casi no se usa con ese significado. O mejor dicho, _las charchas_.

Answer (score 5):

[**Salvavidas**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=X8igOB7)

> 5. m. Cuba y Ur. Pliegue de gordura que se forma en alguna parte del cuerpo.

[**Salvavida**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=X8hlaDs)

> 2. m. Cuba. salvavidas (‖ pliegue de gordura).